# Is it good practice to pass a different model type from a controller to the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have Sales Controller and Products Controller. The Sales Controller has a Create action that returns a view that shows all the products registered in the database. The user must specify the quantity, discount, and the client the items will be sold to before finalizing.

I was wondering if it is good practice for the Sales controller to query the database and pass a different model type (a list of Products in this case).

The action in the Sales controller looks like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ProductRepository productRepository = new ProductRepository();
    List<Product> products = productRepository.ListProducts();
    return View(products);
}
```

My question is: do the actions in a given controller have to strictly pass the same model type of its name?

I also want to search for the client using an input field and retrieve the data using Ajax (if that's even possible), but it's not clear to me whether I should request SalesController or ClientsController.

Sorry if it's a dumb question, I'm still new to MVC and ASP.NET.

Comment: Bit unclear what your asking. You have stated the view is for _specify the quantity, discount, and the client_ yet all your method returns is `List<Product>` which does not even relate to what you display in the view.

Comment: What you do in your controller, what you query and what you return is entirely up to you and your desired workflow. It would be good design to use, for example, the Sales controller for all Sales related actions, including Ajax calls

Comment: The only bad practice in the situation would be inconsistency. If this is how to are going to handle this situation, then handle it like this every time.

Comment: @StephenMuecke I mean that after the page is loaded the user must specify the quantity and discount of a given item/product. After that, he will select the client these items will be sold to. That list will contain all the products currently available.

Comment: Which means that you need to return a model representing what you want in the view (including properties for entering quantities, discounts and selecting the client). That model might might also contain your list of products, but just returning `List<Product>` to the view does not make sense.

Comment: @StephenMuecke you mean using a ViewModel? I always thought that I should pass a bunch of objects to a view using a list. I attended to web programming classes last year but I didn't really understand those concepts.

Comment: Yes, you should be using a view model to represent what your want to display/edit in the view.

Comment: That answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass any type of model to your view. For example it can be a domain model, a list of domain models, a view model, a list of view models, etc. Your possibilities are endless.

When I pass data to a view I normally make use of a view model. A view model will contain data that is supposed to be displayed on a screen.

If you want to display a list of only product-related data on your view and nothing else then I guess it is ok to do the following:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     // productRepository is injected
     List<Product> products = productRepository.GetAll();

     return View(products);
}
```

If you want to display other data on the view in addition to your list of products, then I would normally make use of a view model:

```
public ProductViewModel()
{
     public List<Product> Products { get; set; }

     public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

And then your view could be changed to look like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     ProductViewModel productViewModel = new ProductViewModel();
     productViewModel.Products = productRepository.GetAll();
     productViewModel.Department = "Test Department Name";

     return View(productViewModel);
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is: do the actions in a given controller have to strictly pass the same model type of its name?

No, why would they?

The rule is "don't surprise me". If behavior makes sense, I don't care what you return. If the behavior is nonsensical, returning the "correct" class won't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is: do the actions in a given controller have to strictly
>   pass the same model type of its name?

To add onto Jonathan's answer, there is a caveat to only using the DB models, and that's a lack of flexibility. I always use view models, even if it's a simple page, because as a project evolves, so do requirements. But the best practice for almost any code is to write what makes the most sense to *you*.